# How to access the updated below $scope value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
$scope.widgettype = ' ';
$scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) {
                    $scope.widgettype = data;
                    $scope.showdimaxis = data === 'bubble';
                });
                console.log($scope.widgettype);
```

As new to angularjs, I am just stucked over here. 
Console.log is returning blank value (not the updated one).

How to access the value of $scope.widgettype (updated value) in some other function? Is there any other method to achieve this?

Your help realy appreciated!

Comment: so put it inside `.then`. Your `console.log()` is executed **before** `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

Code on angularjs are asynchronous. So

```
$scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) {
                $scope.widgettype = data;
                $scope.showdimaxis = data === 'bubble';
            });
```

take some milliseconds to be performed.
Try to shift `console.log` inside the then clause.

```
$scope.widgettype = ' ';
$scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) {
     $scope.widgettype = data;
     $scope.showdimaxis = data === 'bubble';
     console.log($scope.widgettype);
});
```

Comment: actually, I want to use the value of the $scope.widgettype in some other function, so for that purpose, as of now to check I am keeping console.log outside of the function

Comment: Okay, you need `widgettype` out of this function. But when you copy some value on $scope it is saved in all scope object.Is the aim of $scope. Binding variable with UI View and make available updates of variable in real time.
You see what I mean?

Comment: If you need widgettype in a different function, pass it as an argument `$scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) { yourOtherFunction(data);}`

Comment: if `yourOtherFunction` is on the same controller is useless passing data as an input. But you can use $scope object. As her have done @Protozoid

As best pratice, so, we can discuss about

Comment: so you mean inn other to access in other function, I have to again have $scope.getwidgettype().then(function ...,  correct?

Comment: The function could be anywhere ... $scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) {RandomService.yourOtherFunction(data);}

Comment: Okay, code is asynchronous, you can't print this updates if you don't "watch" the changement. Pass as an input in another function could be the solution. With callbacks you solve this.
But I suggest you to read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 1):

To use `widgettype` outside of your current function, you need to **return a Promise** (which `$http` already does) **and resolve it** every time you need to retrieve the value.

For example:

```
$scope.widgettype = ' ';
var promise = $scope.getwidgettype().then(function (data) {
    $scope.widgettype = data.data; // `.then` wraps it in an object, so you need `.data`
    $scope.showdimaxis = data.data === 'bubble';
    return data.data; // return the value within a Promise
});
```

And use it elsewhere as:

```
promise.then(function(data){ // resolving it every time we need `data`
    console.log(data); // we returned `data.data`, so this time `.data` is not needed
})
```

---

It's best to write a Service/Factory for this, which might return it like this:

```
return this.getwidgettype().then(function(response) { // return a promise
    return response.data; // and return your data
});
```